# Format date in linq query WP7

Tags: xml, linq, windows-phone-7

I have a linq query showing below

```
    XDocument data = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var persons = from query in data.Descendants("Table")
                          select new MailList
                          {
                              Sender = (string)query.Element("FromUser"),
                              Body = (string)query.Element("Message"),

                              Date = (string)query.Element("mDate"),
                              Time = (string)query.Element("mTime"),

                          };
            EmailList.ItemsSource = persons;
```

I want to format the date in "MM/yy" and the time to "hh:mm"
Thank you

Comment: Hi, What is the type of your date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a Direct Cast with a `DateTime` as it's a value type. Use a normal cast, but beware of an `FormatException` if the date is not formatted correctly.

```
var persons = from query in data.Descendants("Table")
          select new MailList
          {
              Sender = (string)query.Element("FromUser"),
              Body = (string)query.Element("Message"),
              Date = ((DateTime)query.Element("mDate")).ToString("MM/yy"),
              Time = ((DateTime)query.Element("mTime")).ToString("hh:mm"),

          };
```